# undefined method `twitter_sharing_enabled'

Tags: gitlab

I just upgraded my dockerised instance of GitLab from gitlab-ce:latest to gitlab-ee:latest.

Everything seems to work fine, aside from the Admin->Settings page. It just gives me a 500 error and logs this:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `twitter_sharing_enabled' for #<ApplicationSetting:0x00000014a77e48>):
    80:       .col-sm-offset-2.col-sm-10
    81:         .checkbox
    82:           = f.label :twitter_sharing_enabled do
    83:             = f.check_box :twitter_sharing_enabled, :'aria-describedby' => 'twitter_help_block'
    84:             Twitter enabled
    85:           %span.help-block#twitter_help_block Show users a button to share their newly created public or internal projects on twitter
    86:     .form-group
  app/views/admin/application_settings/_form.html.haml:83:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_admin_application_settings__form_html_haml___2805672912369624077_173324520'
  app/views/admin/application_settings/_form.html.haml:82:in `block in _app_views_admin_application_settings__form_html_haml___2805672912369624077_173324520'
  app/views/admin/application_settings/_form.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_admin_application_settings__form_html_haml___2805672912369624077_173324520'
  app/views/admin/application_settings/show.html.haml:4:in `_app_views_admin_application_settings_show_html_haml___3252692826887083853_173266720'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:16:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/readonly_geo.rb:29:in `call'
```

I have cleared the cache and ran migrations with appear to have run fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the exact version of your GitLab:

[`db/migrate/20160331223143_remove_twitter_sharing_enabled_from_application_settings.rb`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/db/migrate/20160331223143_remove_twitter_sharing_enabled_from_application_settings.rb#L0) is fairly recent (13 days ago)

[commit 85cc172](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/85cc1729596ac1e5b31d8cfa1daa07477db6033d) clearly shows `def twitter_sharing_enabled?` *removed*.

That means something in the migration might not have been fully completed.

Comment: Thanks. I have commented out the offending code which resolves the problem for now. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: @brightbulb possible upgrade gitlab and double check the database update process.